# JComboBox popup dynamic population

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jcombobox, population

Having burned up googles search nodes for two days and nights I must humble myself to ask:

Scenario:

- I have a `JTable` with a `JComboBox` as a cell editor.
- I want the `JComboBox` popup list to populate (from an `ArrayList`) at the moment the cell is clicked.

I tried many things (that worked to varying degrees) over a 2-day period but I'm still stumped. I've tried `MouseListener` and listeners. I've also tried `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

I simply need to extend my `JComboBox`, say `DynPopComboBox`, so that when the box is clicked it calls a method to populate its popup list before showing it.  Ideally, I'd want to fetch the popup content either from an `ArrayList` elsewhere in the code or from a different `JTable` in another Object.

Could someone please point me to a code example of this? I'm at my wits end and out of time to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you've done, and why it doesn't work?  As it stands, we don't have a lot to work with.

Comment: Thanks a bunch peeskillet!  It looks like this will do the job.  I added one line with a "cbox.showPopup();"  so that when the population is complete you don't have to click a second time to get the popup.

Answer (score 2):

Override the `getCellEditor()` method of the `JTable` to return the editor with the appropriate editor. Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JPanel
{
    List<TableCellEditor> editors = new ArrayList<TableCellEditor>(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // Create the editors to be used for each row

        String[] items1 = { "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>( items1 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce1 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
        editors.add( dce1 );

        String[] items2 = { "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox2 = new JComboBox<String>( items2 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce2 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox2 );
        editors.add( dce2 );

        String[] items3 = { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox3 = new JComboBox<String>( items3 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce3 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox3 );
        editors.add( dce3 );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                    return editors.get(row);
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Combo Box by Row");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableComboBoxByRow() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```